# iMac reboots while sleeping

Tags: mac, sleep, reboot

I have a two months old, 27-inch iMac, which occasionally reboots itself while sleeping.

My question is: Is there a setting in Mac OSX which could explain this?

Here are previous reasons for reboots:

```
$ log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 1000h
Filtering the log data using "composedMessage CONTAINS "Previous shutdown cause""
Skipping info and debug messages, pass --info and/or --debug to include.
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL  
2019-09-07 10:35:56.591686+0300 0xcf       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 0
2019-09-08 11:10:49.590023+0300 0xcf       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 0
2019-09-15 07:18:29.615022+0300 0xcf       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 0
2019-09-29 06:43:25.667313+0300 0xcf       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Log      - Default:          4, Info:                0, Debug:             0, Error:          0, Fault:          0
Activity - Create:           0, Transition:          0, Actions:           0
```

According to Internet the reported shutdown cause 0 means Power disconnected, however there has been no power failures.

Because the reboot always seem to happen on weekend after a day of no or very light usage, I was wondering if there is some setting in Mac OSX which would explain this. I used the machine for 5 hours on 2019-09-21 and there was no reboot on Sunday the 22nd.

It seems to me that the reboots are just a bit too regular for a hardware problem.

Here are specs about the machine:

- macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6
- iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2019)
- Processor 3,6 GHz Intel Core i9
- Memory 40 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- Graphics Radeon Pro 580X 8 GB

TIA.

Comment: Very similar issue on an 11-year-old machine. Only does it from sleep, never if I keep it awake. I still haven't got to the bottom of it yet… I just gave up & keep it awake now - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368289/previous-shutdown-cause-0-on-mac-pro-2008